# How do I auto-respond to emails from a specific sender to the email recipient in the email body?

Tags: email

I need to auto-respond to emails from a specific sender to a specific mailbox to the email recipient in the email body.

The email body will be consistent such as:

```
From: <noreply@Acompany.com>
Date: August 15, 2015 at 7:22:00 AM CDT
To: <receiver@bcompany.com>
Subject: Customer Referral

Hello Name,
The following customer has indicated an interest in your services. Outlined below are the specifics for this referral:
•   Service: my service 
•   Customer Name: Joe Howard 
•   Customer Phone Number: 0207 123 4567 
•   Customer Email Address: abc@company.com 

Please contact this customer as soon as possible to ensure premier service.
```

I need to be able to auto-respond to abc@company.com  with a email message  begin with "Hello Joe,"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What mail stack are you using?

Comment: What is mail stack?  I think the emails are send via SMTP, if that is what you refer to

Comment: SMTP is the protocol. What I am asking is what mail server, filter and maybe other email processing tools you have hooked up. I am expecting an answer like Postfix and Sieve.

Comment: I believe it is an exchange server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using Exchange service- EWS, as the mail server is Microsoft exchange server. Here is the documentation on EWS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice(v=exchg.80).aspx
cheers!